# Why are placeholders used in python?

Tags: python

```
a = "hello"
b = 32
print('%s %d' % (a, b))
print(a,b)
```

Both print statement will give out same output i.e hello 32.
But using print(a,b) is much easier then the other method so why the concept of placeholders exist in python.

Comment: Say, you have `c = 123`. It's an order number, so when printing a report, you want it appear padded to the length of 8 (or whatever), like so: `00000123`. With format strings, this is trivial. I'd like to see how you would approach this, without format strings.

Answer (score 2):

Because sometimes you want to put things other than spaces between items.  What if I wanted to take a name, email address, and employer and generate some formatted result?

```
d = { "first": "Patrick",
      "last": "Haugh",
      "email": "Patrick.Haugh@example.com",
      "job": "My Job"}

print("{first} {last} <{email}> {job}".format(**d))
# Patrick Haugh <Patrick.Haugh@example.com> My Job

print("{last}, {first}: {job} <{email}>".format(**d))
# Haugh, Patrick: My Job <Patrick.Haugh@example.com>
```

You can then write code that accepts a format string, so the code itself doesn't have to change if you want to change how you format your output.  I recommend you read the documentation of the [`Format String Syntax`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) to get more of an idea of what is possible.